# Multiple environment declarations for TypeScript?

Tags: angular, typescript

I've been searching for a way to emulate Angular's handling of different environments with its `staging.environment.ts` and `production.environment.ts` in vanilla TypeScript, however could not find a single mention of it anywhere. The TS compiler options don't mention anything that would allow me choose between different environment files to include in compilation.

What I'm ultimately looking for would be a CLI flag allowing me to do exactly this. Have I missed something somewhere?

Comment: you may try to follow this article: https://dev.to/nikosanif/using-shared-settings-between-multiple-environments-in-angular-1d0e

Comment: @akkonrad I've seen plenty of solutions that are specific to Angular - however not vanilla TypeScript. What I'm looking for is the latter, a solution not building upon Angular. Thanks for the recommendation though!

Comment: There is no such thing as "environments" (it's an Angular artificial construct). You can simulate those by creating objects with the same interface and different values and choosing which one to use at runtime based on some condition.

Comment: You can use webpack to swap out the environment files. This isn't supported by typescript alone.